# The RSA Algorithm

Tags: algorithms

My public key is $e=41$, $m=63680341$, and $y=62723227$. How do I decipher into plaintext the ciphertext $y$? The professor gave a hint and said that the plaintext is hello in a foreign language. My job is to find $x$ using

$$x=D(y)=y^d \mod m.$$

I tried breaking $63680341$ into primes but I got lost after that. Please help!

Comment: Is $m$ what is typically called $n$?

Comment: YES m is typically called n

Comment: did you ever converge on this?

Answer (score 3):

- $y = 62723227$
- $e = 41$
- $m = 63680341 = p \times q = 7211 \times 8831$
- [*Euler totient*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totient): $\varphi(m)= (p-1)(q-1) = 63664300$
- $d = e^{-1} \pmod {\varphi(m)} = 41^{-1} \pmod {63664300} = 55900361$

$$\mbox{Message} = y^d \pmod{m}$$

Comment: So is it 62723227^55900361 (mod 63664300)?

Comment: It is -->> mod $m$

Comment: I am still not getting a foreign language for the word hello. I used the 26 letters of the alphabet but I'm still getting jumbled words

Comment: He encoded the message using base 26 which are the 26 letters in the alphabet.

Comment: In the alphabet system he gave us A-y is 1-25 and z is represented as 0. He never gave an example where numbers had to be combined but since it is a big number numbers like 13 and 12 can be combined

Comment: http://www.omniglot.com/language/phrases/hello.htm - maybe you can work it out from this list after rechecking everything.

Comment: There are no typos and your calculations are right because that is where I got stuck.

Comment: Yes I got that number and the way he is doing it is he writes how many time 5051035 can go into 26. So that is 11x26^4 plus the remainder which is 24299. In his example he wrote 217=8x26+9.8 was h and 9 was I and he got hi.

Comment: Yes I figured out how he got his hi, but I cant get a foreign word hello with the number I have

Comment: Nope. I tried that already. He did the powers of 26 to get that. 217 can only go into 26, 26^1, which is 26. Then he did 217 divided by 26 which gives you 8. Something. That how he got 8x26 with a remainder of 9. In my case 5051035 goes into 26, 26^4 plus 24299.

Comment: Don't leave us in suspense! @Ellen - what is the answer?

Comment: That's the thing I don't know. I keep getting a bunch of letters that do not relate to a foreign way to say hello.

Comment: Nice work, Amzoti! +1

Comment: The answer is 5051035. The word is Kaixo which is hello in Basque language. You keep breaking down 5051035 by powers of 26 until you can't go anymore.